# Delete Button on Cart (SFCC)

Tags: javascript, commerce-cloud, b2c

I need to do a task which consists in :

- Apply a delete button for each item on minicart
- Apply a delete button for ALL the products on CartPage.

The project has some customizations but nothing very different from storefrontbase. The exception they were not using the delete-button but now they want it.

So I did the same logic from storefrontbase about the delete-button from minicart.

But something weird happened, the Button only works on CartPage and all the another points from website(Home,Pdp,Search...) it did not work.

What do you think it could be happening? What kind of tips you can do to solve this task and work with server side? I did not have so much trainning on the part and i having struggling.

The code is the same from storefrontbase.

Thanks